# Converse of Fundamental Theorem of Line Integral

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields

[image]

Why is this converse not called the Fundamental Theorem of Line Integral? It resembles the first part of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, which comes the first.

Also, Wikipedia presents this theorem and then proves it assuming $F$ is continuous and the domain is open and path-connected. Does path independence imply the latter assumptions? If not, are there any counterexamples to the theorem?

Comment: linking to the page would be far better than a huge picture that is unreadable at normal size.

Comment: Probably because when it was in vogue to identify "fundamental" theorems, this result was seen as almost a corollary to the FTC, whose only new concept was one that was pretty obvious: If you are going to define a function by integration along paths, and multiple paths are possible to the same point, then you need to require that the integration gives the same result over all such paths. (And note that we don't prove this condition here - it is an assumption.)